# Difficulty integrating c libsodium output with PHP

Tags: c, libsodium

My goal is to create a small C program that will generate output which can later be parsed by PHP (which now has a built-in wrapper for libsodium).

The problem I am having is that PHP is complaining bitterly about the output from my C program.   This is probably no surprise as I am very experienced with PHP, but only have limited experience with C.

For example running the `sodium_crypto_box_seal_open()` wrapper in PHP yields a null output.

My PHP usage is correct because I have coded an entire implementation of the C code below just using the PHP wrappers and it works fine (encrypts OK and decrypts correctly).  So I suspect the problem is the C output that I am feeding PHP.

Here is my C code (the core file-encryption content between the `// Encrypt file START` and `// Encrypt file END` tags is the example code from the libsodium website, the rest is my newbie C coding !):

```
#include <sodium.h>
#include "filedata.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CHUNK_SIZE 8192
void doEncrypt(char * inKey,char * plainText,char * cipherText,char * outKey) {
    //Get input key
    //const char *inputKey=readFile(inKey);
    const char *inputKey="aQFsJJuU65zXKzqDfS1KuxqqebkER/cPqno+oZL5PgQ="; // testing with a fixed value....
    unsigned char * inputKeyBin=sodium_malloc(crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
    size_t bin_len;
    const char *b64_end;
    if (sodium_base642bin(inputKeyBin,sizeof(inputKeyBin),inputKey,strlen(inputKey),NULL,&bin_len,&b64_end,sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL) !=0) {

        printf("sodium_base642bin() failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Encrypt file START
    unsigned char *key;
    unsigned char buf_in[CHUNK_SIZE];
    unsigned char buf_out[CHUNK_SIZE+crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_ABYTES];
    unsigned char header[crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_HEADERBYTES];
    crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_state st;
    FILE *fp_t,*fp_s;
    unsigned long long out_len;
    size_t rlen;
    int eof;
    unsigned char tag;
    key=(unsigned char *)sodium_malloc(crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES);
    crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_keygen(key);
    fp_s = fopen(plainText, "rb");
    fp_t = fopen(cipherText, "wb");
    crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_init_push(&st, header, key);
    fwrite(header, 1, sizeof header, fp_t);
    do {
        rlen = fread(buf_in, 1, sizeof buf_in, fp_s);
        eof = feof(fp_s);
        tag = eof ? crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_TAG_FINAL : 0;
        crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_push(&st, buf_out, &out_len, buf_in, rlen,
                                                   NULL, 0, tag);
        fwrite(buf_out, 1, (size_t) out_len, fp_t);
    } while (! eof);
    fclose(fp_t);
    fclose(fp_s);
    // Seal Key
    unsigned char * sealed=sodium_malloc(crypto_box_SEALBYTES+crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES);
    if (crypto_box_seal(sealed, key, crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES, inputKeyBin) !=0) {
        printf("crypto_box_seal() failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fp_o;
    fp_o = fopen(outKey,"wb");
    fwrite(sealed,1,sizeof sealed,fp_o);
    fclose(fp_o);
    // Encrypt file END

    const size_t outSz=sodium_base64_encoded_len(crypto_box_SEALBYTES+crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES,sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);
    char * base64Out=sodium_malloc(outSz);
    sodium_bin2base64(base64Out,outSz,sealed,crypto_box_SEALBYTES+crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES,sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);
    printf("E:  %s\n",base64Out);


    const size_t outSzX=sodium_base64_encoded_len(crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES,sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);
    char * base64OutX=sodium_malloc(outSzX);
    sodium_bin2base64(base64OutX,outSzX,key,crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES,sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);
    printf("K:  %s\n",base64OutX);
```

My PHP code at the moment is simply this :

```
$keyPair=\sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(\base64_decode($privK),\base64_decode($pubK));
$ok=$sealedDataFromC;
echo $ok.PHP_EOL;
$ky2=\sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(\sodium_base642bin($ok,\SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL),$keyPair);
echo \base64_encode($ky2).PHP_EOL;
```